# How to prevent overwritting elements, when line breaks in subgraph titles in mermaid?

Tags: markdown, mermaid

**Background:** I want to use mermaid to visualize the structure of my code. Therefore I need to display the name and some extra information (here: run time of a loop) for some functions.

**Problem:** Adding the extra information should be done by a line break of the subgraph titles. My problem is that the second line ("Run-Time: 100s") is overwritten by the nodes in the subgraph.

**Question:** Does anyone know how to stop this behaviour?

```
flowchart TB 
A["BootCV()"]
subgraph D["LM.CV() <br> Full Run-Time: 193"]
direction TB
            DA["lm()"] -.-> combine_results
        end
A -.-> D
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a bug inside of Mermaid.js, but a hacky workaround that can fix this is to use an invisible node and link to add some spacing:

```
flowchart TB 
A["BootCV()"]
subgraph D["LM.CV() <br> Full Run-Time: 193"]
direction TB
            DA2-->DA
            class DA2 disable;
            classDef disable display:none;
            linkStyle 0 display:none;
            DA["lm()"] -.-> combine_results
        end
A -.-> D
```

The spacing cannot be controlled, as it is hardcoded in the SVG and can't be manipulated using CSS.

Comment: Perfect, that works very well! Two follow-up questions for clarification:
1. What does `classDef bring_down margin-top:400px;` do? I noticed no difference, when deleting it. 
2. Is there any other way to point on the link to hide in `linkStyle 0 display:none;` than to count its index number? Would be hard when a graph gets bigger

Comment: The `bring_down` class was me testing the styling features of Mermaid.js, I update the answer to remove it now. Unfortunately there isn't another option as of now to style the links other than indices.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment on previous answer, because I don't have high enough rep. But I need to add to @simon-ress's answer:

`linkStyle 0 display:none;` doesn't work anymore, but they introduced an invisible link. However, you can create like this: `DA2~~~DA`

Comment: Would you mind please editing this into a standalone answer?